# How to add more colors to SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

**What I have:**
I am using SharePoint Online from Office 365.
I've created a color coded SharePoint calendar using overlay.

**What I want:**
I want to use different colors for color coding than those proposed by SharePoint
(The current colors are very dark and not distinctive)

**What I already know:**
Changing anything in this version of SharePoint is very difficult as it is not supported by Microsoft.
I can't add a script web part in this version (as far as I know but it was checked thoroughly) and I am yet to find out how to add CSS customization without using third party software (which I can't do as I am the admin of only my site, not the organization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors are controlled by the css classes from ms-acal-color1 to ms-acal-color9 stored in Themable/corev15.css. And the color options are based on the site theme.

As you cannot add script web parts or upload custom css files to the site, the only way is to change the look of the site:
[image]

Comment: As far as I know this way will only change the look when it's switched to classic from modern experience. Can you confirm that I'm wrong and maybe just doing something incorrectly?

Comment: @Ania there is no modern calendar interface (yet?)

Comment: @Ania As I said, the color coding is based on the site theme. Change the look would also change the color coding.

Comment: @Robert thank you, I'll use this solution.
Does the fact that there is no modern calendar interface mean, that custom CSS added to the website will work on it? (I checked and it is possible to add CSS directly to the site, but it affects only the classic experience and I don't want to switch to it in other parts of the site)

Comment: @Ania, yes that is correct

Comment: @Robert thank you, then that seems to be the solution, at least until SP Calendar is "modernized"